# R: Missing data causes error with XGBoost / sparse.model.matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, xgboost

As far as I can understand, XGB should have the benefit of dealing with missing data, however, whenever I test the Boston housing set with a few NAs added, I get the error:

```
The length of labels must equal to the number of rows in the input data
```

The code I am running is

```
trainm <- sparse.model.matrix(class ~ ., data = train)
train_label <- train[,"class"]
train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(trainm) label=train_label)
```

When I don't add the NAs everything runs fine. I am pretty sure that the issue is that the NAs are removed from a sparse matrix which causes the confusion, but I am not sure how to address it.

My code is [here](https://pastebin.com/Z7rmMBsn).

Any feedback that can help me on will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The problem isn't the `NA`. The number of observations in `train_label` is different of the number of observations in `trainm`. If you do a `dim(trainm)` you'll get `369 x 15` while `length(train_label)` returns you `403`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I out comment the '### Add a few NAs' section (line 29-33), then everything works fine, so unless I misunderstand something, the error is caused by having some data missing?

Comment: Yes, if you comment these lines of your code you will be able to run the `xgb.DMatrix`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do corrective action for handling NAs while building sparse model matrix. Rest there is no problem wit your code/data. This is the modified code:

```
options(na.action='na.pass')
trainm <- sparse.model.matrix(class ~ ., data = train)
train_label <- train$class
train_matrix <- xgb.DMatrix(data = trainm, label=train$class)
```